# ImageView isn't shown when added to LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, view, android-support-library

I'm using a support library  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'`
When I'm trying to add a view dynamically to other layout image is missing.

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_task"` image isn't shown when i use this in image view.

And works when I write like this `android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_task"`

What could be wrong?

### **Here's the ImageView**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_task"
        android:id="@+id/remove_sub_task_icon" />
```

**The code is here, from previous question:**
[Adding view to LinearLayout dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305248/adding-view-to-linearlayout-dynamically)

Comment: Show the full code. So many things may have happened there. Did you set the size of the `LinearLayout` ? Where did you add it ? Are you sure it was added ?

Comment: is the image vector?

Comment: @JonZarate, I edited a question and added a code above.

Comment: @Pulkit, Yeah, the image is vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it by myself. The problem was in inflating the view.
You have to initialize inflator like this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Instead of this:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Android Support Library 23.3.0, **support vector drawables** can only be loaded via app:srcCompat

you need to add **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** to your build.gradle file

```
    // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

and make sure that app uses the proper namespace as follows:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: I have in my gradle code this, already(

`defaultConfig
 {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
 }`

Comment: check the xml file for the namespace of xmlns:app

Comment: In layout? Or image

Comment: in layout after this line of code `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Nothing( No result.

Comment: Can you add the whole xml layout code in the above question

Comment: Here are all of codes conected to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305248/adding-view-to-linearlayout-dynamically

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: why have you made width 0dp in ImageView?
Maybe try changing it to wrap_content

Comment: because I've set a weight for this view. I aleady have changed, that's not the problem(